# Why does iMessages change the URL I pass to it via the UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, imessage

my code is very simple, but there's a bug somewhere and I can't seem to figure this out.

**Step 1:**

```
// create an array that contains this url
NSArray *items = @[[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://danzafuerte33.as.me/YogaPrivate"]];

UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:shareController animated:true completion:nil];
```

**Step 2:**
The activity view controller modal will show up, and one of the choices will be **iMessages**.

**Step 3:**
Tap on iMessages -- notice that the correct url is shared -- so far so good

**Step 4:**
Tap cancel on the iMessages modal window, the `UIActivityViewController` should still be visible

**Step 5:**
Tap on iMessages again, the url is changed to https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12808744 which is not the right url!

Why on earth is this happening the second time iMessages opens this link, is this an iMessages bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the url is passed to iMessages, it retrieves the web site in order to render a preview.

At the top of the page returned is:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12808744">
```

This says that the canonical link for this page is https://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=12808744, and so the activity item is updated with this, preferred, url for the page.

Comment: great insight, I'll check this out locally and see if it's fixed if I change the canonical link. Something else is boggling me though!
Why is this only happening the second time around (after the user cancels the UIActivityViewController and not when it's first presented (it works fine the 1st time)???

Thanks!

Comment: It happens the second time because it has had an opportunity to fetch and cache the preview.  You will notice the first time you open iMessage it takes a few seconds for the preview to appear, while the second time it is instantaneous.

Comment: got it. I noticed apple uses og: links too, but I can't find any documentation on wether they're using `og:url` at all.

Do you think we can get away with keeping the same canonical link but changing the og:url instead?